# Default interactive 'back swipe' is disabled when using custom interactive transition

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

In my app I have a custom interactive transition for some view controllers. I am talking about `UINavigationController` interactive transitions for push/pop. For all other view controllers, I want to use the default iOS interactive transition (swiping from left to right to go back).

To activate my custom interactive transition I have to implement a `UINavigationControllerDelegate` and implement the `animationControllerFor` callback. This works fine! But if I try to return `nil` for some cases, meaning I don't want my custom transition and instead use the default one, it disables the back swipes completely!

Code to reproduce the issue:

```
class MainNavigationController: UINavigationController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self
    }

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController,
                                 animationControllerFor operation: UINavigationControllerOperation,
                                 from fromController: UIViewController,
                                 to toController: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Use this `MainNavigationController` and all your back swipes will be disabled inside this navigation controller! I wasn't expecting this. Because the documentation says about the return value:

> The animator object responsible for managing the transition animations, or nil if you want to use the standard navigation controller transitions.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontrollerdelegate/1621846-navigationcontroller

Does anyone have any idea whether I am doing something wrong or if this is a bug? I tried this on both iOS 11 and iOS 12 beta.